# Overriden HandleAuthenticateAsync method in AuthenticationHandler in ASP.Net Core Web Api is called twice with different headers

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have one application that sends a GET request to another application.
This request is generated once, and sent once. I have validated this by generating a System.Net.HttpWebRequest object, populating it, and debugging my workflow until I call request.GetResponse(). This is only called once.

In the application that recieves the request, I have overriden the AuthenticationHandler's HandleAuthenticateAsync method with some custom authentication logic. When I debug the request, my validation works, and I return a  valid AuthenticateResult. However, immediately after this returned, my app goes into the HandleAuthenticateAsync a second time. This time the request is missing the Authentication header, and the app therefore returns a 401 response.

Does anyone have any clue what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The answer for me was to remove app.UseHttpsRedirection(); from Startup.cs' Configure method, since I was calling this application through http://localhost for testing purposes.